# Place with entraces or gates

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Is there any `Places` `API` to show place suggestions with its entrances, for places like **Airport, Stadium and Temples/Pagodas**? For example, if the user types "**Shwedagon**", the suggestions should also include its entrances(South, East, west and north). I have tried `Google`, `Foursquare` and `HereMap` 's API. But found nothing regarding this. Is there any other way to do that??

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps and the Directions API will offer different routes depending on the travel mode (driving, walking, transit) and origin, when the destination has multiple entrances suitable for the selected travel mode.

For instance, there are 3 entrances to the Heathrow Airport:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Heathrow+Airport/@51.4700223,-0.4564842,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x48767234cdc56de9:0x8fe7535543f64167!8m2!3d51.4700223!4d-0.4542955

Driving directions will approach the airport through a different tunnel depending on where you're driving from. You can see this by dragging the origin around, but you need to drop it somewhere before you see the route changing to a different tunnel: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Ashford,+UK/Heathrow+Airport,+Longford+TW6,+UK/@51.4487356,-0.4658601,14z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x4876714cb4a7f863:0x5c295c6795a7d155!2m2!1d-0.4552643!2d51.4274516!1m5!1m1!1s0x48767234cdc56de9:0x8fe7535543f64167!2m2!1d-0.4542955!2d51.4700223!3e0

Bewhare that "Heathrow Airport" is a rather ambiguous destination: which terminal?

Airports may have terminals with different entrance points, e.g. Heathrow Terminal 3 has a single entrance and no matter where you drive from, directions are through the tunnel on the North side:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Ashford,+UK/Heathrow+Airport+Terminal+3,+Longford,+Hounslow,+UK/@51.4707319,-0.4568065,16z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x4876714cb4a7f863:0x5c295c6795a7d155!2m2!1d-0.4552643!2d51.4274516!1m5!1m1!1s0x487673cd3278a04b:0x7745cf10b0211870!2m2!1d-0.4567217!2d51.4719247!3e0

However, this is subject to availability of such data. Google Maps does not have entrance / gate for all places in the world.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!! I am trying to do with customization of our own now..

Comment: have you found on this regarding entry gates? i'm stucked in this can;t find any solutions for this

Comment: I am looking for a solution for this too.  Please update here if you have found some way to get the entrances from Google Places API (or any other source).  Thank you

Comment: I need the same solution for Heathrow Airport only as my client's taxi booking website prices vary based on the terminal and passenger's location. Is there any updates in Google Map API?

Comment: The new Places API (New) may help you with this, it introduces a new field (subDestinations) for Unique places that are related to a particular place. For example, airport terminals are considered sub-destinations of an airport. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/reference/rpc/google.maps.places.v1#subdestination